# How do I combine 2 arraylist into a list of lists in java

Tags: arraylist

I want to convert 2 arraylists to an arraylist list of arrays

newList3 = [-50, 30, -20, 0, 20, -30, 50]

newList4 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

I want to return:
[[-50, 1], [30, 1], [-20, 1], [0, 1], [20, 1], [-30, 1], [50, 1]]

The only result I can get is:
[-50, 1, 30, 1, -20, 1, 0, 1, 20, 1, -30, 1, 50, 1]

I have tried

```
a = newList3.get(0);
b = newList4.get(0);
newList.add(a);
newList.add(b);
newList.add(newList2);
newList.clear();
a = newList3.get(1);
b = newList4.get(1);
newList.add(a);
newList.add(b);
newList.add(newList);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation you are looking for is called **zip operation**.

```java
IntStream
    .range(0, Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size()))
    .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.asList(list1.get(i), list2.get(i)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here, Since we'll be iterating over the lists we need the index. So, we're using `IntStream.range` to generate the index ranges. And then we're using the `mapToObj` to zip the 2 lists.

And in range, we're going from `0` to the list size which has minimum elements.

Comment: Java changed a lot since 2012. It's js like today :-).